# Project Euler Problem #1 - Not getting the right answer

Tags: python

I keep getting the wrong answer. I've looked up other peoples code and even though theirs are similar to mine, i still keep getting the wrong answer.

```py
sum = 0

for t in range (1000):
        if (t % 3 == 0 or t % 5 -- 0):
                sum = sum + t

print(sum)
```

The answer i keep getting instead is 433165

Comment: what is `--` in `t % 3 == 0 or t % 5 -- 0`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have syntax issue as @eyllanesc pointed. Just change it to this, it will be fine:

```
sum = 0

for t in range(1000):
    if t % 3 == 0 or t % 5 == 0:
        sum += t

print(sum)
```